# Using HTC wildfire for android development

Tags: android

I would like to know whether is it possible to use my HTC wildfire (some links would be nice) for android development instead of the emulator.

I have tried to find the information by Google, but so far no useful results.

If I get more information, I'll update here.

[image]

[When I used wildfire with eclipse, I got this.]

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From your screenshot, it looks like you do not have the permissions set properly to access the USB device.

Either try to run the adb service as root:

```
$ sudo adb kill-server; sudo adb start-server
```

OR, the more permanent solution is to set up udev rules for USB device permissions. See the instructions in step 3 of the android [Developing on a Device](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html) page.

Log in as root and create this file: /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules. The udev system checks this file for special cases when devices are detected.

Edit the file to read:
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666"

This sets permission bits on the dev node to world read and writeable for the special case where the USB vendor ID is equal to 0bb4.

Now execute:
chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

... gives world read permission to these android rules which is needed to let the udev daemon process this new rule.

Comment: Thank you so much... I got it running on my device.

Comment: I used kill-server instead of stop-server

Answer (score 2):

Sure, all you need is to install the USB driver and follow the directions from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html).
The USB driver is included in the HTC Sync software, which you can get [here](http://www.htc.com/www/supportdownloadlist.aspx?p_id=312&act=sd&cat=all).

Comment: I tried that ... but still not able to connect the phone. I have enabled debugging mode in my phone as told but still no use. I also tried in ubuntu (still no use)

Answer (score 1):

Go to htc website

http://www.htc.com/europe/SupportViewNews.aspx?dl_id=982&news_id=769

and download the driver

and just connect the htc phone to the pc and run the application from eclipse.

No configuration needed. It directly runs on the phone instead of emulator.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The only other thing I can think of is how you've set your phone to connect via usb-to-computer...   And that might just solve my own similar problems... I'm using "HTC Sync" as my connection style, when I haven't even tried the others.

Lets find out, shall we?

Nope.  Connection type didn't matter at all.  "Charge Only", "disk drive", "usb tethering", it didn't change my behavior at all (I can launch apps, but logcat shows nothing from my app, and my breakpoints are ignored).

Sounds like it's time for a new question.

Answer (score 0):

If device still not detected (???), after updating  /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules as suggested earlier, also unplug and re-plug the usb cable into the device.