# Connect android device on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.3

I want try my application on a chinese device with android.

I try to

`lsusb` shows :

```
Bus 001 Device 04: ID 18d1:0002 Google Inc.
```

In /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules I put :

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="18d1", MODE="0660"
```

But it doesn't work.

I can't see my device with `adb devices`
(usb debug is enabled)

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19291975/2176962

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this case one, try to change your 51-android.rules by :

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="18d1", MODE="0666"
```

and restart adb

edit : to restart adb `adb kill-server` then `adb devices`

Comment: How could I restart adb please ?

Comment: Use `adb kill-server` then `adb devices`

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Goo is basically correct, but not best practice.

`SUBSYSTEM==”usb”, ATTR{idVendor}==”18d1″, MODE=”0660″, GROUP=”plugdev”`

is a better way to achieve it, because the rights are granted for the group `plugdev` and not for everyone.

Afterwards add your user to the `plugdev` group with this command:

`sudo adduser [username] plugdev`