# Restart adb untill success wth bash script commands

Tags: android, linux, bash, shell, adb

There is annoying issue with device which very often get this:

```
List of devices attached 
????????????    no permissions
```

Due the fact we lack time I wanted to write simple bash script that would get restart the `adb` untill this `device` get `permissions`, something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

alias_to_adb_dir/adb kill-server
alias_to_adb_dir/adb start-server

while [$? -ne "???????????? no permissions"]; do
   alias_to_adb_dir/adb kill-server
   alias_to_adb_dir/adb start-server
done
```

I would appreciate any `solutions`.

Comment: Why do you want to restart `adb`? The `????????????    no permissions` issue has nothing to do with `adb` restart

Comment: Huh, No offence but guese it has.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460656/android-debug-bridge-adb-device-no-permissions. But the question is more how to achieve this kind of command flow with bash. Can you answer this ?

Comment: None taken. People upvote bad practice answers because they do not know better and the question you linked is a prime example.

Comment: For proper way to setup `adb` in linux read http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/09/the-most-comprehensive-write-up-on-how.html