# Permission denied on ADB

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I am using Ubuntu 64 bit Ubuntu 14.4 LTS.
When I am trying get Android Device Monitor from android Studio "Initialising ADB" dialog shows forever.

Event Log error is

```
IllegalArgumentException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb": error=13, Permission denied
```

Im using JDK java-7-oracle

Im getting list of devices on

```
adb devices
```

from terminal.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Most probably it is USB permissions issue
please see this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460656/android-debug-bridge-adb-device-no-permissions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try all these:

1. confirm that you get adb version by typing adb version in console. If working check the adb which is running is from`/home/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb`. use `which adb` for this.
2. Check AVD manager and check that android tools are installed.
3. Check that adb wasn't installed by other user.
4. Install IA32 if you are using 64 bit architecture.
5. Check permission for android sdk folder. if not give `chmod -R 777 platform-tools`.
6. Check platform-tools folder is added to your path.

Try Try!

Comment: adb is not from my android sdk.

Comment: sorry, I removed my comment! And good you resolved your problem.

Answer (score -2):

Install the 32bit library

apt-get install ia32-libs

Comment: E: Package 'ia32-libs' has no installation candidate

Comment: refer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23182765/how-to-install-ia32-libs-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts-trusty-tahr