# adb devices => no permissions (user in plugdev group; are your udev rules wrong?)

Tags: java, android, linux, adb, android-source

I am getting following error log if I connect my android phone with Android Oreo OS to Linux PC

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
xxxxxxxx    no permissions (user in plugdev group; are your udev rules wrong?);
see [http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html]
```

I tried with the link provided by  the error message but still getting same error.

Comment: I had the same issue and solved following the steps from the link. `adb` was installed manually and added to my path (fresh install of Linux) but I kept getting the error. I proceeded to remove it and install it again via `apt install adb` (Ubuntu-based distro). After that I've doubled checked that my user was, in fact, part of the `plugdev` group, rebooted the machine and plugged in the device again. Got the permission dialog displayed and all worked as expected without any hacking. :)

Comment: Just run it with sudo https://stackoverflow.com/a/15043526/3957754

Comment: just do it 

sudo apt-get install android-sdk-platform-tools-common

Comment: `sudo apt-get install -y android-sdk-platform-tools-common && sudo cp /lib/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/`

Comment: @Mokkun comment worked like a charm on my Rpi Zero.

Answer (score 446):

Check device vendor id and product id:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 078: ID 138a:0011 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS5011 Fingerprint Reader
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 5986:0652 Acer, Inc 
Bus 002 Device 081: ID 22b8:2e81 Motorola PCS 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Here my android device is Motorola PCS. So my `vid=22b8` and `pid=2e81`.

Now create a udev rule:

```
$ sudo vi /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="22b8", ATTR{idProduct}=="2e81", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

Now the device is good to be detected once udev rule is reloaded. So, let's do it:

```
$ sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
```

After this, again check if your device is detected by adb:

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
ZF6222Q9D9  device
```

So, you are done.

If it still doesn't work, unplug/replug the device.

If it still doesn't work, restart your OS.

Comment: This answer is a more durable solution as the file transfer (MTP) workaround doesn't persist as well across device reboots, etc.

Comment: This s/b the accepted answer.

Comment: Don't laugh, but I actually had to reboot Mint in actually for this to work, seemed that the `udevadm` command was being ineffective.

Comment: @HenriquedeSousa Had to unplug and plug back, which triggered "allow this computer ..." dialog on the Android device.

Comment: @HenriquedeSousa I had to do the same on mint.

Comment: does not work for me

Comment: Worked for me. Before "flutter devices" gave me "Android Null (API null)". And now "Android 10 (API 29)". Thanks

Comment: How come we name the file: `51-android.rules`? I.e. why the 51?

Comment: It works! Thanks. Fedora doesn't have plugdev group, so ignore GROUP="plugdev" if you use Fedora.

Comment: Just an update - running `sudo udevadm trigger`, followed by re-plugging  the device worked for me (didn't require a reboot) on Linux Mint.

Comment: Going through the USB / tethering settings on the device (pull down global notifications menu) and switching to File Transfer and disabling tethering worked for me.

Comment: On a Xaomi Redmi Note 8, Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, I had to add it to the 51-android.rules file (SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="ff08", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev") and then choose file transfer mode in the popup dialog when I plugged in the device.

Comment: What would I do without stackoverflow ...

Comment: Used a combination of this answer as well as this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/12664045/2356570.

Comment: Everything worked for me after rebooting the system. But in general, everything is correct!

Comment: I think switching between recovery mode and fastboot changes the idProduct. So, you can omit ATTR{idProduct} part  in the rule. Cheers

Comment: If you are on Ubuntu, you can install the `android-sdk-platform-tools-common` package, which contains a community-maintained default set of udev rules for Android devices: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device#setting-up

Comment: I ended up adding 2 lines `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="d00d", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"` and 
`SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2717", ATTR{idProduct}=="ff48", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"`

Comment: it is useful for me . after change udev rules, reload rules, then replugin my devices, it works , thank u!

Answer (score 230):

I don't know the reason behind this issue. But a temporary fix would be to set the phone to **File Transfer mode** or **MTP mode**.

The problem with this fix is that you'll need to set the mode from charging mode to File transfer mode or MTP mode every time the cable is connected.

Comment: for some reason, this work. Change to File Tranfer mode and device asked for permission. Then adb kill-server adb start server and now my device is recognized. tks

Comment: The reason this works is because it changes the `pid` in `lsusb` to one which is in your `udev` rules

Comment: android 10 it worked !!!thanks

Comment: This works if you want just `adb`, but for `fastboot` to also work, you need to use the other answer.

Comment: revoking usb debugging authorizations also works (permission dialog pops up)

Comment: Same issue happened with me! enabling the file transfer mode solved all sorts of trouble, Thanks!

Comment: @Pieter, I don't think so. This answer worked for me whereas the answer to edit udev rules had not (well, I had not restarted, only replugged, but I'm against mindless reboots). I guess not all usb connection modes support adb connection.

Comment: Works for me on Android 13 and Debian 12.