I don't find the waydroid configuration
I want to start mobile development with expo. My OS is Ubuntu 22.04. When I type the command npm run android it shows me I don't have android device or emulator. After numerous of problems and bug, I realized that my android device can't connect to my PC via USB so I can't adb to connect my device.
Then I decided to use Waydroid, which is an android emulator for linux.When I try to launch Waydroid I have this error :
user@computer$ waydroid show-full-ui
[12:48:51] Starting waydroid session
[12:48:51] WAYLAND_DISPLAY is not set, defaulting to "wayland-0"
[12:48:51] Wayland socket '/run/user/1000/wayland-0' doesn't exist; are you running a Wayland compositor?

However, I don't use wayland but I use X11. I would like to configure Waydroid to use X11. However I can't find where are the configuration files on waydroid.
When I check in ~/.config, I don't find it, same at /opt/ and /etc/. When I go to the documentation, I don't find any information about that.

Have you set-up the udev rule for your USB device to allow adb server communicating with it? https://stackoverflow.com/q/14460656/150978

Yes I did it ! But it doesn't work. When I typed adb devices, I had nothing.
